# Why cant I create a generic list of my class type?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public int i = 1;
        public string str = "Chandan";

    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<Class2> Object2 = new List<Class2>();

    }

}
```

Comment: You're not trying to do "Object2.i" are you? Or "Object[0].i" without first adding at least one instance of Class2 to the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't create"? Any errors (runtime, compile time)? What did you expect, what happened? In short, please provide *some* information that allows someone to react.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works for me.

Comment: Now you don't even have a question anymore. You just posted code that compiles and does nothing.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Kudos for his optimization skills though. I mean, it does the _nothing_ really _fast_! :-)

Comment: How about posting code that actually doesn't compile so we see your problem?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry guys. I found the answer. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Class2> Object2 = new List<Class2>(new[]{ new Class2(); });
Console.Out("{0}. {1}", Object2[0].i, Object2[0].str);
```

Should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a *collection* of your objects.

In order to access the public fields of *each* object, you need to access each object in the list.

Did you mean?

```
Class2 Object2 = new Class2();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Class2> Object2 = new List<Class2>();
Object2.Add(new Class2());
Console.WriteLine(Object2[0].str);
```

I see no reason why `Object2[0]` shouldn't have accessible fields. And I just tested in LinqPad, and it worked correctly.

Or alternatively without a List:

```
Class2 Object2 = new Class2();
Console.WriteLine(Object2.str);
```

It's usually bad style to use public fields, but apart from that your code is ok and works.

Comment: If public fields are "bad style", then why do they exist? I think that a more accurate statement would be that there are times when they are a good choice, and times when they are not the best choice. From the information given, you cannot assess whether they are a good choice in this situation.

Comment: when I instantiate the Object2 by saying new list<Class2> the object should get instantiate but i am not getting the two variables in the object

Comment: @DOK the fields here are non static, non readonly and not related to native interop. So it's pretty clearly not one of the cases where public fields are good style. But I assume it's just to make the example simpler.

Comment: Adding the word "usually" helps.

Answer (score 0):

Output of the following code 
List count = 1

```
public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public int i = 1;
        public string str = "Chandan";
        public string Data()
        {
            return i.ToString() + " " + str.ToString();
        }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Class2 Object1 = new Class2();
        List<Class2> Object2 = new List<Class2>();
        Object2.Add(Object1);
        Response.Write("List count = " + Object2.Count.ToString());    
    }

}
```

You are right Matt. Thanks for the explanation. You Rock!!!